# Remove <param> node from <object> and replace it with new <param> values

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

How can I add  tag to Object , replacing its original  tag with modified values. I am using the JavaScript to perform this replacement.

But the param is not getting replaced or removed.

how to identify a particular param under

Can any one suggest please.
Thank you!

```
function autoObjectFun() {   

var objects = document.getElementsByTagName('object');
var len1 = objects.length;
  for(var j = 0; j < len1; j++) {

   var paramObj = objects[j].getElementsByTagName('param');
   var len = paramObj.length; 

        for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) { var srcStr = paramObj[i].getAttribute('name'); if (srcStr == 'flashvars' ) { var newParamObj = document.createElement('param');  newParamObj = paramObj[i].cloneNode(true); var params = paramObj[i].getAttribute('value'); var newparams = ''; var paramplay = 'autoplay=0&'; newParamObj.setAttribute('value', paramplay);

paramObj[i].removeNode(true);

var newObject = objects[j].cloneNode(true);

var parent1 = objects[j].parentNode;
   newObject.appendChild(newParamObj);

parent1.replaceChild(newObject,objects[j]); }

}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no native method **removeNode()**, this will cause an error and stop the further execution of your statements.

Try:

```
paramObj[i].parentNode.removeChild(paramObj[i]);
```

..instead.